# Is there a built-in container which maps int -> element?

Tags: python, dictionary, optimization, standard-library

I need something very similar to a standard `dict` which is being used to map integers (ranging from 0 to several hundreds) to arbitrary elements:

```
d = {}
d[5] = "hello"
d[100] = "world"
d[70] = "pretty"
```

Unfortunately I need to (read-)access `d` very often and `dict` becomes quite slow. And additionally I also need the order of elements being kept and a way to access elements by this order. E.g:

```
>>> d.order_at(0)
hello
>>> d.order_at(2)
pretty
```

I wrote myself a dict-like container which is much faster than `dict` by using a `list` internally and uses the keys as indices:

```
    class IntDict:
        def __init__(self):
            self._by_key = []
            self._by_index = []

        def __contains__(self, int_key):
            return int_key < len(self._by_key) and self._by_key[int_key] is not None

        def __getitem__(self, int_key):
            return self._by_key[int_key]

        def __len__(self):
            return len(self._by_index)

        def __setitem__(self, int_key, value):
            assert value is not None
            self._by_key += [None] * (int_key - len(self._by_key) + 1)
            if self._by_key[int_key] is None:
                self._by_index.append(int_key)
            self._by_key[int_key] = value

        def order_at(self, index):
            return (self._by_key[self._by_index[index]]
                    if index < len(self._by_index) else None)
```

But this has some obvious downsides:

- it's self written and has to be maintained, explained and tested
- large keys result in high memory consumption because `d[100000] = 1` leads to a list of `100000` `None`s
- technically I had to store tuples of `(bool, <element)` in order to know whether or not an element has been set to `None` or not set yet (needed for `_by_index` list)

So I'm wondering if there's already an implementation which solves my issues magically..

Comment: How can dict he slow? It's the fastest data structure available.

Comment: Can you share the situation in which the usage of `dict` became slow?

Comment: To add to Andrej's comment, it would be good if you could post a small, self-contained benchmark that is representative of your use case and demonstrates the slowness.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: You don't need to  store tuples of `(bool, <element)` to know how an element was set. You can create your own unique value with `NULL = object()` and use that as the filler value — and such a value `is not None`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman A hash table can be too slow compared to other data structures for some use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Python's default `dict` implementation is really quite fast. But, incases where you want to access `n'th element` from a dict easily, I would suggest using an `OrderedDict`. From python 3.7, `dict` retains insertion order, so you can just use the standard `dict`

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d=OrderedDict()
>>> d[5] = "hello"
>>> d[100] = "world"
>>> d[70] = "pretty"
>>>
```

**For python 2.7**

```
>>> d.items()[2]
(70, 'pretty')
```

**For python 3.x**

```
>>> n = 2
>>> list(d.items())[n]
(70, 'pretty')
```

Converting the dict's items to list might need lot of memory and can be slow when the dict is large and there is not enough memory.
So a better way is to use `next` and `islice`

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> n = 2
>>> next(islice(d.items(), n, n+1))
(70, 'pretty')
```